# Render non-activerecord objects in JSON/XML [RoR]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, activerecord

I am testing a small whois API using the ruby gem whois, and due to the format of whois responses being quite funny sometimes i was asked not to use ActiveRecord for saving the responses.

Simply put, here's how it works :

1. User inputs a domain name in a form from a view (action 'lookup' = creating a request)
2. Controller catches the parameter then sends to model (non activerecord) by instanciating the request object [containing the whois response]
3. Model uses the whois gem and sends back to controller the whois response
4. Controller sends a response in different formats (html/json/xml) but only html gets the object.

Here is the code for the action "lookup" of my controller "requests" :

```
def lookup
domain = params[:domain]
@request = Request.new.search(domain)

respond_to do |format|
  if @request != nil
    format.html
    format.json { render :json => @request}
    format.xml {render :xml => @request}
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @request.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

Obviously, i'm having a hard time because i'm not using ActiveRecord, and since RoR is expecting one he keeps spitting nilClass exceptions.

So when i go on `localhost:8080/requests/lookup` everything is displayed fine, and @request contains all the data i want.
But wether `localhost:8080/requests/lookup.json` or `localhost:8080/requests/lookup.xml` nothing shows up and if I try giving instructions in the builders (Jbuilder/XMLBuilder) it throws a nilClass exception, proving that the variable scope isn't so global...

And no, i don't think putting in the variable session is a good idea : I will only be using it for a single query.

If needed, i'll be happy to provide more of my code if it may help you understand my problem. I know AR is the way to go, but nonetheless i am curious as to know how to get around it for situations such as this one.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You can use ActiveModel even though you are not using ActiveRecord. Rails 4 made it really easy. You can also add [ActiveModel::Serialization](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serialization.html) which allows you to serialize the objects with `.to_json` and `.to_xml`

```
class WhoisLookup
  include ActiveModel::Model
  include ActiveModel::Serializers::JSON
  include ActiveModel::Serializers::Xml

  attr_accessor :search_term # ...

  # you can use all the ActiveModel goodies
  validates :search_term, presence: true, length: {in:2..255}
end
```

ActiveModel::Serialization will allow you to use:

```
format.json { render :json => @result } # calls @result.to_json
```

PS. don´t use `@request` for variable naming (@result maybe?) you´re bound to run into issues and confusion with `ActionDispatch::Request`.

Comment: So far JSON works, cheers. But for the xml format, rails throws a nilClass exception when I call "to_xml" on my object. Any ideas ?

PS: i call on that object for JSON, so i'm pretty sure its not nil. Which is why i fail to unterstand...

Comment: Anything useful in the stacktrace? Did you create a serializer class for your "Request" model? https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers

Comment: Yup, i've used the serializers (XML and JSON).
I've been byebugging the app and basically when i call the method "to_xml" on "Request" (wich i renamed "Whois" on your advice) it goes straight into **ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer::OutpuBuffer#safe_concat**
But why ? I have no idea...

Comment: I´m guessing that is starts building the XML document in the buffer.

Comment: You might want to start a new question on this subject.

Comment: Yeah, i'll make a new thread to avoid polluting the comment section, since it should makes things clearer. I'll post the link when i'm done as well.

Comment: Here is the link <a>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26848385/active-model-xml-serialization-undefined-method-for-nilnilclass</a>