# Active Model XML serialization : undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, activemodel

Originally from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26806564/render-non-activerecord-objects-in-json-xml-ror/26809295), i'm posting a new thread to focus on my issue resolving around the "to_xml" method.

What i'm trying to do : make a conversion from a ruby Object (Whois::Record) to XML.

I am currently using ActiveModel but not ActiveRecord (eg previous [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26806564/render-non-activerecord-objects-in-json-xml-ror/26809295) for reasons)

Here is the relevant controller :

```
def lookup
   domain = params[:domain]
   @whois = Request.new
   @whois.search(domain)

   respond_to do |format|
     if @whois != nil
       format.html
       format.json {render :json => @whois.body}
       format.xml {render :xml => @whois}
     else
       format.html { render :new }
       format.json { render json: @request.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
     end
   end
end
```

Please note that *@whois* is **NOT** a *Whois::Record object*, but a class that contains such object (in the **body** *property*)

And the view :

```
<% if @whois != nil %>

    <%= @whois %>
    <!--JSON-->
    <%= @whois.body.to_json %>
    <!--XML-->
    <% byebug %>
    <%= @whois.to_xml %>

<% end %>
```

Note that the *to_json* method works fine, so the fact that ruby throws a *nilClass exception* is quite weird.

Here is the stacktrace starting from **to_xml** :

> /home/nico/.rvmruby (2.1.3) gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/xml_mini.rb:148:in `_dasherize'
>   /home/nico/.rvmruby (2.1.3) gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/xml_mini.rb:140:in`rename_key'
>   /home/nico/.rvmruby (2.1.3) gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/xml_mini.rb:119:in `to_tag'
>   /home/nico/.rvmruby (2.1.3) gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/conversions.rb:88:in`block (2 levels) in to_xml'
>   /home/nico/.rvmruby (2.1.3) gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/conversions.rb:88:in `each'
>   /home/nico/.rvmruby (2.1.3) gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/conversions.rb:88:in`block in to_xml'
>   /home/nico/.rvmruby (2.1.3) gems/builder-3.2.2/lib/builder/xmlbase.rb:175:in `call'
>   /home/nico/.rvmruby (2.1.3) gems/builder-3.2.2/lib/builder/xmlbase.rb:175:in`_nested_structures'
>   /home/nico/.rvmruby (2.1.3) gems/builder-3.2.2/lib/builder/xmlbase.rb:68:in `tag!'
>   /home/nico/.rvmruby (2.1.3) gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/conversions.rb:87:in`to_xml'
>   app/models/request.rb:26:in `to_xml'

Byebug gives me a lead as such :

**to_xml** > ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer::OutpuBuffer#**safe_concat**

```
   153:     def safe_concat(value)
=> 154:       raise SafeConcatError unless html_safe?
   155:       original_concat(value)
   156:     end
```

*note* : *html_safe?* is set at 'true' here, and value equals "\t"

**original_concat**

*File activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/output_safety.rb, line 132*
 **Alias to original_concat**

```
def concat(value)
  if !html_safe? || value.html_safe?
    super(value)
  else
    super(ERB::Util.h(value))
  end
end
```

And when i step over i come back to the to_xml method, that's throwing a tantrum about not having a class to call upon methhods. I would be grateful for any help, thanks.

**Edit**

Here is the class Request from my model :

```
#This is a generic class for checking Key authenticity and sending requests to the engine
#Furthermore, this class will contain the WHOIS response in body

include ActiveModel::Model
include ActiveModel::Serializers::JSON
include ActiveModel::Serializers::Xml

attr_accessor :body

def attributes
    {body => nil}
end


def to_xml(options = {})
    to_xml_opts = {:skip_types => true} # no type information, not such a great idea!
    to_xml_opts.merge!(options.slice(:builder, :skip_instruct))
    # a builder instance is provided when to_xml is called on a collection of instructors,
    # in which case you would not want to have <?xml ...?> added to each item
    to_xml_opts[:root] ||= "instructor"
    self.attributes.to_xml(to_xml_opts)
end

def search(domain)
    # since rails compiles the code before executing a search once,
    # we have to catch niClass exceptions and such
    if domain != ( nil && true && "" )
        c = Whois::Client.new
        self.body = c.lookup(domain)
    end
end
```

I've used this as from what i've understood XML tries to define a type for each attribute, and has problems with named objects. Here's the [thread about to_xml and objects in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6808958/to-xml-doesnt-work-on-objects-returned-through-rails-activerecord-habtm-referen)

Comment: Error is from the line `app/models/request.rb:26:in 'to_xml'`. What is the code in that line?

Comment: Why isn´t it `format.xml {render :xml => @whois.body}`? Could you add the class definition of whatever class `@whois.body` is?

Comment: I have edited my question to answer both of you (they were relevant to my model).
@Santosh : the 'to_xml' method here overrides the usual method. See here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6808958/to-xml-doesnt-work-on-objects-returned-through-rails-activerecord-habtm-referen] for reference.

Comment: @papirtiger : the class Request is using the 'whois' gem to return a whois response that is stored inside 'body'. Basically Request.body == Whois::Record.